# How do I send the message to chain from service activator

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement to send the message to a chain from service activator and return back to the service activator and continue the flow.

Thanks in advance.
Mahendra

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) and inject it into your class that's invoked by the service activator.